# Reading fixed width file with two width schemes

Tags: r, readr

I want to read in a large fixed width file to R. The fixed width file contains two types of rows. That is: the rows that start with "A" contain variables defined by one set of widths and the rows that start with "B" contain variables defined by another set of widths. A toy example based on `mtcars`:

```
AMazda RX4           21.0 160.0
BHornet 4 Drive       1  0    3
BHornet Sportabout    0  0    3
AMazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
ADatsun 710          22.8 108.0
AHornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
BValiant              1  0    3
AHornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
BDuster 360           0  0    3
```

Currently, I read the files in with two `readr::read_fwf` commands and drop the `B` rows after reading in the `A`s and vice versa. But of course, for a large fixed width file, this means reading the data in twice. And, if some string variables in `A` overlap in position with some numeric variables in `B`, then `read_fwf` gets the (eventual) column types wrong and I have to deal with that downstream (this is not the case in the toy example below).

Any clever ideas to improve the speed and workflow?

My current "solution":

```
example <- "
AMazda RX4           21.0 160.0
BHornet 4 Drive       1  0    3
BHornet Sportabout    0  0    3
AMazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
ADatsun 710          22.8 108.0
AHornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
BValiant              1  0    3
AHornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
BDuster 360           0  0    3"

library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

in_a <- read_fwf(example, fwf_widths(c(1, 20, 4, 5), c("code", "name", "mpg", "disp"))) %>%
  filter(code == "A")

in_b <- read_fwf(example, fwf_widths(c(1, 20, 4, 3, 3), c("code", "name", "vs", "am", "gear"))) %>%
  filter(code == "B")
```

Results

```
> in_a
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  code  name                mpg  disp
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     Mazda RX4          21     160
2 A     Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160
3 A     Datsun 710         22.8   108
4 A     Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258
5 A     Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360
> in_b
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  code  name                 vs    am  gear
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B     Hornet 4 Drive        1     0     3
2 B     Hornet Sportabout     0     0     3
3 B     Valiant               1     0     3
4 B     Duster 360            0     0     3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (if you only have the two types) is to use the `comment=` argument:

```r
library(readr)
in_a <- read_fwf("~/StackOverflow/jfeigenbaum.txt", fwf_widths(c(1, 20, 4, 5), c("code", "name", "mpg", "disp")),
                 comment = "B")
in_a
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   code  name                mpg  disp
#   <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     Mazda RX4          21     160
# 2 A     Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160
# 3 A     Datsun 710         22.8   108
# 4 A     Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258
# 5 A     Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360
```

If you have more than 2 types and want to generalize it a little, you can use `pipe()` and grep things out (using the command-line `grep`, not the R function `grep()`).

```r
read_fwf(paste(readLines(pipe("grep ^A ~/StackOverflow/jfeigenbaum.txt")), collapse = "\n"),
         fwf_widths(c(1, 20, 4, 5), c("code", "name", "mpg", "disp")))
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   code  name                mpg  disp
#   <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     Mazda RX4          21     160
# 2 A     Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160
# 3 A     Datsun 710         22.8   108
# 4 A     Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258
# 5 A     Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360
```

Unfortunately, while `readr::read_table` can now use `pipe(...)` as a connection-based input, it appears that `read_fwf(pipe(...))` does not work, so we need the temporary (and admittedly less-efficient) workaround above. (If your data is not large, this should not pose a problem.)

And finally, if your data is truly a string, you can `grep()` it out after splitting into individual lines:

```r
example <- strsplit("
AMazda RX4           21.0 160.0
BHornet 4 Drive       1  0    3
BHornet Sportabout    0  0    3
AMazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
ADatsun 710          22.8 108.0
AHornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
BValiant              1  0    3
AHornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
BDuster 360           0  0    3", "\\n")[[1]]

read_fwf(grep("^A", example, value = TRUE),
         fwf_widths(c(1, 20, 4, 5), c("code", "name", "mpg", "disp")))
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   code  name                mpg  disp
#   <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     Mazda RX4          21     160
# 2 A     Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160
# 3 A     Datsun 710         22.8   108
# 4 A     Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258
# 5 A     Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360
```